# DEP: Sysinternals Process Explorer != static analysis != BinScope

Tags: windows-7, security, binary-files, sysinternals

I have an executable running ("heidisql.exe"). The **Sysinternals Process Explorer** shows `"DEP (permanent)`" in the column DEP.

I checked the binary statically (among other things using **pestudio**). The static analysis results all said that DEP is *not* supported, that is, the `IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_NX_COMPAT` bit is not set.

Why does the Process Explorer show `DEP (permanent)` then?

To make it even stranger: **BinScope**  (free tool from Microsoft) does not list the result of the '`NXCOMPAT check`' at all, neither under 'Failed checks', 'Checks that didn't complete' or 'Passed checks'. What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: Does it x86 or x64 executable?

Comment: Its a 64bit Windows Application. See http://www.heidisql.com/download.php?download=installer

Comment: AFAIK, DEP is forced for x64 processes, since it was no legacy DEP unaware x64 code in the first place.

Comment: I googled but could not find a clear source for that. Do you have one? The closest I could find was this: "This means that all 64-bit processes are always protected. The only way to prevent DEP from protecting a 64-bit application is to turn it off completely." See http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-xp/disable-turn-off-dep-windows/

Comment: I do not have link right now. I will try to find one, when get on more comfortable device, than I am on now.

Comment: Thanks! I read that DEP is enabled on 64bit Systems by default. But I could not find a clear statement that it is forced for x64 processes.

Comment: Did you find the time to digg up a reference?

Comment: *DEP is “always on” for 64bit processes on 64bit versions of Windows and it cannot be disabled.* [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2009/06/12/understanding-dep-as-a-mitigation-technology-part-1)

Comment: @PetSerAl thanks for the link. Do You want to transform this into an answer so I can upvote that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2009/06/12/understanding-dep-as-a-mitigation-technology-part-1) says:

> DEP is “always on” for 64bit processes on 64bit versions of Windows and it cannot be disabled.

Also, this [Microsoft documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53314) says this:

> On 64-bit versions of Windows, if hardware-enforced DEP is available it is always applied to 64-bit processes and kernel memory spaces and there are no system configuration settings to disable it.

and this:

> **Per-application DEP configuration**
>   For the purposes of application compatibility when DEP is set to the `OptOut` policy level, it is possible to selectively disable DEP for individual 32-bit applications. However, DEP is always enabled for 64-bit applications.